# Discord.js Ping Pong command with cooldown

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm very new to coding so it's probably horrible. Here's the code

```
    let userCooldown = {};

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.includes('ping'))
    if (userCooldown[message.author.id]) {
        userCooldown[message.author.id] = false;
        message.reply('Pong');
        setTimeout(() => {
            userCooldown[message.author.id] = true;
        }, 5000) // 5 sec
    }
})
```

the plan would be for the bot not to respond to the message for 5 seconds until it's written again

Comment: What currently happens? We need to know so we know which part to modify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you set the cooldown to `false` if it's `true` when someone sends a message and why you set it to `true` after five seconds.

If your `userCooldown` includes the users who currently can't execute the function, you need to check if they are already on that list. If they are, don't execute the function. If they are not, execute the function, add them to the list and use `setTimeout` to remove them after five seconds. Try to run the snippet below:

```js
let userCooldown = {};

function onMessage(message) {
  console.log(`onMessage fired with message: "${message.content}"`);

  if (message.content.includes('ping')) {
    // if user can't execute the fucntion, just exit
    if (userCooldown[message.author.id]) return;

    // if they can, add them to userCooldown
    userCooldown[message.author.id] = true;
    console.log('Pong!');

    // and remove them after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      userCooldown[message.author.id] = false;
    }, 5000);
  }
}

// run it every second to test it :)
let message = { content: '!ping', author: { id: 'authorID' } };
setInterval(() => onMessage(message), 2000)
```

Comment: i modified some parts of the code, "function onMessage" i replaced with "client.on" and on someplaces, where it needed i replaced "console.log" with "message.reply" and it still worked. thank you fellow hungarian friend!